# How to make gem5 wait for GDB to connect to reliably break at the start of simulation and see start_kernel of the Linux kernel?

Tags: gem5

On QEMU, I can use `-S -s`, which waits for GDB to connect before starting the simulation

How to do the same thing on gem5, hopefully with the `fs.py` script?

By the time I swap terminals and connect, the simulation has already gone past `start_kernel`.

I saw the `--debug-break` flag, but I don't know how to use it, if I do:

```
--debug-break=1
```

The run just fails with:

```
Trace/breakpoint trap   (core dumped)
```

- https://www.mail-archive.com/gem5-users@gem5.org/msg15206.html
- https://www.mail-archive.com/gem5-users@gem5.org/msg09298.html

**Edit**: after looking a bit further, I now found that commit c2baaab0ed43ad09fc8b7fcda25207b6ccd6c0e3 adds a parameter:

```
+    wait_for_remote_gdb = Param.Bool(False,
+        "Wait for a remote GDB connection");
```

which must be what I'm looking for. But I didn't find how to enable it from `fs.py`, seems to not be exposed?

Answer (score 0):

After the addition of `--param` at 34efcae1b532df56a7ef65f0e4b76179c9bc9479 you can now just do:

```
gem5.opt fs.py --param 'system.cpu[0].wait_for_remote_gdb = True'
```

then connect gdb:

```
arm-linux-gdb -ex 'file vmlinux' -ex 'target remote localhost:7000'
```

and you are left at the very first instruction.

Here is a [highly automated setup](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/tree/8815312cad053d0284c4d91bfbf36a1e9ea207af#baremetal-gdb-step-debug).

Remember that aarch64 is broken at 34efcae1b532df56a7ef65f0e4b76179c9bc9479: https://www.mail-archive.com/gem5-users@gem5.org/msg15383.html

Before `--param` e.g. at 7bfb7f3a43f382eb49853f47b140bfd6caad0fb8, apply this tiny patch instead:

```
diff --git a/configs/example/fs.py b/configs/example/fs.py
index 3997ed76c..b4267ebc0 100644
--- a/configs/example/fs.py
+++ b/configs/example/fs.py
@@ -376,5 +376,6 @@ if buildEnv['TARGET_ISA'] == "arm" and options.generate_dtb:
             sys = getattr(root, sysname)
             sys.dtb_filename = create_dtb_for_system(sys, '%s.dtb' % sysname)
 
+test_sys.cpu[0].wait_for_remote_gdb = True
 Simulation.setWorkCountOptions(test_sys, options)
 Simulation.run(options, root, test_sys, FutureClass)
```

https://gem5-review.googlesource.com/c/public/gem5/+/27287 (March 2020) added a `--wait-gdb` option to se.py which has the same effect as using `--param`.